# Wait for Android emulator to be running before next shell command?

Tags: android, shell, android-emulator

I started an Android emulator using the following shell command:

```
emulator -avd TEST_AVD
```

The emulator starts just fine, but the shell script never finishes executing. It just hangs there even after the emulator has completed startup. I have tried with a number of other arguments that I could find, but nothing could quite do what I want it to. How do I know, or stop the shell command, when the emulator is ready to go?

I am setting up our Jenkins CI to use a Jenkinsfile to start the emulator, and then run a series of gradle commands. In short, I'd like to do this:

```
sh "emulator -avd TEST_AVD"
sh "./gradlew clean test spoon"
```

However, I don't want to run the gradle tasks until the emulator has finished startup, and I can't figure out how to do that in the terminal.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you want to do something after you start the emulator you should start it in the background

```
emulator -avd TEST_AVD &
adb wait-for-device
# other stuff here
```

`adb` can wait for a device over a transport to be in a particular state

```
  adb wait-for[-<transport>]-<state>
                               - wait for device to be in the given state:
                                 device, recovery, sideload, or bootloader
                                 Transport is: usb, local or any [default=any]
```

Comment: This helped a lot, thanks. Now I just need to find a way to read the status until it's started, and go from there. I will come back if I find something.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. wait-for-device might be exactly what I need. Going to give it a test run.

Comment: Upvoted and accepted because this did what I asked for. If you have time, wondering if I could take this question one step further.

This completes when the device is opened, but /not/ when it's done booting. (aka I see this complete while it's still showing the "android" animation). Any idea how I can go as far as to wait for it to be completely booted, and on the home screen?

Comment: True, the device is considered ready when adb can connect, then you can have `shell` and perhaps you can search for something in the log or just wait (i.e. `sleep 30`) some time. As this is intended for CI this wait will not be relevant.

Comment: You can also wait for `boot_completed` property set.

Comment: Or use [AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) to wait for some specific View on the screen.

Comment: Ooh, will try `boot_completed`. I have googled around for documentation on the `wait-for` command, but I must be using all the wrong keywords, I can't find it. Do you know where I can view the possible arguments? Thank you SO much for your help.

Comment: DERP oh my gosh I'm such a noob. Thank you!

Answer (score 16):

To wait until device (or emulator) boots, you can do something like this (as was [already answered by Пионерка](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/83726/how-to-adb-wait-for-device-until-the-home-screen-shows-up/164050#164050)):

```
adb wait-for-device shell 'while [[ -z $(getprop sys.boot_completed) ]]; do sleep 1; done;'
```

Basically:

1. Wait for device/emulator to be in adb `device` state
2. Open shell & sleep in 1 second intervals until the `sys.boot_completed` property becomes true

Answer (score 10):

If anybody would be interested what Android Studio does, when running emulator, the answer is [this class](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/adt/idea/+/studio-master-dev/android/src/com/android/tools/idea/avdmanager/EmulatorConnectionListener.java):

1. If device is online, then it is ready. No need to go to further steps.
2. Checks system property `adb shell getprop dev.bootcomplete` until it is equal to 1
3. For API 23+ devices runs command to unlock screen: `adb shell wm dismiss-keyguard`
4. Waits 1 second.

Comment: I'm getting a 404 for the given link. The closest I could find was this: https://github.com/JetBrains/android/blob/abd1f189043f83ffbb3be33e60fc925deaeae831/android/src/com/android/tools/idea/avdmanager/EmulatorConnectionListener.java However, from what I can tell the checks it is using aren't nearly as involved - it just does steps 1 & 2.

Comment: Link is fixed and description accordingly.